# Electron positron annihilation to more the 3 photons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter, positronium

I  understood why a single photon can't be released from the annihilation of an electron and positron and that the common cases are 2 and 3 photons. I have two thing's I'm unsure of:

1. why is the probability to let say 5 photons is less the let say 3? why is the probability go down as we increase the number of photons?
2. how come we can have 2 and 3 photon emissions and still conserve the energy. is the energy gap between singlet and triplet states in positron sufficient to produce more photons?

Comment: Only the 2 photon decay (of an electron & positron initially at rest) produces 511 keV photons, so energy conservation isn't an issue.

Comment: i understood that the physics allows  the system to be split into any number of photons just that the probability for more then 3 is small. even though it it's small  if it happens does each photon has less energy then ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium#Formation_and_decay_in_materials lists the various ways that the annihilation can happen, with rough probability estimates. [Decays of Positronium](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9911410) by Czarnecki & Karshenboim gives some useful details. The (4 photon / 2 photon) branching ratio of para-positronium is ~$1.49×10^{-6}$, the (5 photon / 3 photon) branching ratio of ortho-positronium is ~$1.0×10^{-6}$.

Comment: Energy conservation *must* be obeyed, so the total photon energy must equal the original energy of the electron + positron system, that is, their rest mass-energies, plus their kinetic energies and potential energy.

Comment: why the fact that there are more photons means less probability ?

Comment: We can model a simple decay by [tossing a coin](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/633564/123208). Annihilation is a bit like tossing multiple coins or dice at once. Here's a crude model. We have 3 dice, and rolling a six means the annihilation decay occurs. If we roll 1 six we get 1 pair of photons, if we roll 2 sixes the decay releases 2 pairs of photons, and if we roll 3 sixes the decay releases 3 pairs of photons. Actual annihilation is a little more complicated, but hopefully that gives you the general idea.