# How did physicist calculate times like $10^{1500}$ and $10^{10^{76}}$ years?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, astrophysics, time, quantum-tunneling

If protons don't decay, iron stars are expected to form via quantum tunneling after $10^{1500}$ years, and they are expected to all have become neutron stars or black holes after $10^{10^{26}}$ to $10^{10^{76}}$ years. How did physicists calculate these insane values?

Comment: Is your question different to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270004/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to estimate tunnelling timescales [by the WKB approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation#Approximation_away_from_the_turning_points). Your quoted figures are taken from Eqs. (41) and (47) in [Dyson 1979](https://fisherp.scripts.mit.edu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/RevModPhys.51.447.pdf) ([this version](http://www.aleph.se/Trans/Global/Omega/dyson.txt) is easier to search). While Eq. (41) follows from Eqs. (30) and (40) (the former summarizes usage of the aforementioned approximation), Eq. (47) follows from Eqs. (30) and (45).

### First timescale

Let $m,\,m_p$ denote the electron and proton masses, and $M\approx\frac14Am_p$ the reduced mass of two $\frac12A$-nucleon nuclei that fuse to form ${}_{26}^{56}\text{Fe}$. In terms of the fine structure constant $\alpha=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon c\hbar}$ and a characteristic length scale $d=Z^{-1/3}\alpha^{-1}\frac{\hbar}{mc}$,$$\begin{align}U&=\frac{Z^2\alpha c\hbar}{4d}\\&=\frac{Z^{7/3}\alpha^2mc^2}{4},\\\sqrt{2MU}&=A^{1/2}Z^{7/6}\alpha c\sqrt{\frac{mm_p}{8}},\\S&=\frac{2d}{\hbar}\sqrt{2MU}\\&=A^{1/2}Z^{5/6}\sqrt{\frac{m_p}{2m}},\\e^S&\approx10^{1487.46}.\end{align}$$

### Second timescale

For a radius-$R$ iron star of $N$ electrons, $M=2Nm_p$ and $U=\frac{N^{5/3}\hbar^2}{2mx^2}$ in the non-relativistic regime, so$$S=N^{4/3}\sqrt{\frac{8m_p}{m}}\ln\frac{R}{R_0},$$where $R_0$ is the radius at which relativity becomes relevant. If the logarithm is $1$,$$N=10^{56}\implies S\approx10^{2.44\times10^{76}}.$$